Replacing Multiple Phrases in Multiple Word Docs with AppleScript
I've been trying to use Gemini to help me write a script for the task in the title.
I tried this code:
-- Set up the phrases to find and their replacements (ensure proper formatting)

set textToFindList to {"May 23, 2023", "Aboriginal Day", "June 21", "2023"}

set textReplaceWithList to {"May 24, 2024", "National Indigenous Peoples Day", "June 20", "2024"}

-- Ensure the lists are the same length
if (length of textToFindList) is not equal to (length of textReplaceWithList) then return

-- Choose the folder containing the Word documents
set folderPath to POSIX file "/Users/stirlingtait/Documents/Donation Letters"

tell application "Finder"
    -- Look for both .docx and .doc files
    set fileList to every file of folder folderPath whose name extension is {"doc"}
end tell

tell application "Microsoft Word"
    repeat with fileRef in fileList
        open (fileRef as alias)
        set doc to active document
        tell doc

            -- Print the list content for verification (optional)
            -- display dialog textToFindList
        
            repeat with i from 1 to length of textToFindList
                set oldPhrase to item i of textToFindList
                set newPhrase to item i of textReplaceWithList
            
                -- Create a new find object and set its properties
                set findObject to find object of text object of selection
                tell findObject
                    set content to oldPhrase
                    set replacement text to newPhrase
                    set forward to true
                    set wrap to find stop
                    execute replace all with match case -- Replace all occurrences
                end tell
            end repeat
            save
            close
        end tell
    end repeat
end tell

display dialog "Replacement complete!"

and got this error:

error "Can’t set «class 1650» of missing value to "May 23, 2023"."
number -10006 from «class 1650» of missing value


I encountered a number of problems which I don't remember and which could be newly introduced, but TBH my experience with AppleScripting Word is quite old and not very extensive.
The main problems seem to be that

you can't just reference the selection (even though the Word dictionary suggests you can
trying to tell the FindObject something seems to work for the content property but not for the replacement property
there are a few syntax errors which you may not have found out if your tests haven't reached that part of your code

This is code that worked here - you may need to check the code that looks for both doc and docx (perhaps you changed it to simplify testing?)
-- Set up the phrases to find and their replacements (ensure proper formatting)

set textToFindList to {"May 23, 2023", "Aboriginal Day", "June 21", "2023"}

set textReplaceWithList to {"May 24, 2024", "National Indigenous Peoples Day", "June 20", "2024"}

-- Ensure the lists are the same length
if (length of textToFindList) is not equal to (length of textReplaceWithList) then return

-- Choose the folder containing the Word documents
set folderPath to POSIX file "/Users/stirlingtait/Documents/Donation Letters"    

tell application "Finder"
    -- Look for both .docx and .doc files
    set fileList to every file of folder folderPath whose name extension is {"doc"}
end tell


    tell application "Microsoft Word"
        repeat with fileRef in fileList
            open (fileRef as alias)
            -- setting doc to active document caused problems later
            tell active document
                - I seemed to have to select something
                select text object
                -- Print the list content for verification (optional)
                -- display dialog textToFindList
                
                repeat with i from 1 to length of textToFindList
                    set oldPhrase to item i of textToFindList
                    set newPhrase to item i of textReplaceWithList
                    
                    -- Create a new find object and set its properties
                    -- I had to specify ' of active pane of active window'
                    set findObject to find object of selection of active pane of active window

                    -- I had to omit the tell FindObject block and spell everything out
                    set content of findObject to oldPhrase

                    -- changed 'replacement text' -> 'content of replacement'
                    set content of replacement of findObject to newPhrase
                    set forward of findObject to true
                    set wrap of findObject to find stop
                    
                    --  a couple of syntax changes in here.
                    execute find findObject replace replace all with match case -- Replace all occurrences              
                end repeat
                save
                close
            end tell
        end repeat
    end tell
    
    display dialog "Replacement complete!"

